# Split the data binding of KnockoutJS into table C#

Tags: c#, parsing, dictionary, knockout.js, binding

I have a tag with data-bind = "value: contents" for an input tag in KnockOutJS

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: contents" />
```

It displays in following format {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}

I'm building a table with name and value then split those keys and values separately and display in TDs

```
<td>
    <strong>
         <span id="textKey" data-bind="text: displayKey" />    
    </strong>
</td>

<td>
         <input id="textValue" type="text" data-bind="value: displayValue" />
</td>
```

Could you help me some ideas of how I can split those keys and values into Dictionary<> and into columns and rows in my case?

Thank you

Comment: For conversion into dictionary, you can check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873562/parse-json-in-knockout-into-dictionary-key-value-in-c-sharp/23875302#23875302

Comment: Hi @GôTô infact, it was me again in your previous post and thanks a lot for your help, but now Im facing one thing that the data of keys and values are not coming from the predefined value in the JS, it comes from the data-bind of the input tag, and I have no right to modify the "contents" in data-bind, so now I wonder if I can put the mapDictionaryToArray(contents) right in the cshtml input tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have control over the structure of `contents`, you can use the conversion to array created in your previous thread like this:

Html

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: mapDictionaryToArray(contents())">
        <tr>
            <td> <span id="textKey" data-bind="text: $data.key"></span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="textValue" type="text" data-bind="value: $data.value" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ViewModel

```
var viewModel = {
        contents: ko.observable({
            "reference": "2Z94",
                "car_id": "9861"
        }),
        mapDictionaryToArray: function (dictionary) {
            var result = [];
            for (var key in dictionary) {
                if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    result.push({
                        key: key,
                        value: dictionary[key]
                    });
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/v9BNr/6/)**

Comment: Thanks GoTo, I have split the js into multiple files: like in this example, but then I still cannot get the data from the converted dictionary, could you have a look at those files here : http://notepad.cc/temobu53 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Knockout to populate a HTML table, you can use an `observableArray` with a `foreach` data binding. See here for a working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BMat/)**, which uses the below code:

**View Model:**

```
var vm = {
    contents: ko.observableArray([{
        "displayKey": "Fruit",
        "displayValue": "Bananas"
    }, {
        "displayKey": "Colour",
        "displayValue": "Red"
    }, {
        "displayKey": "Car",
        "displayValue": "Ferrari"
    }])
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea style="width: 500px; height: 90px;"
data-bind="value: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(contents()))"></textarea>

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: contents">
        <td> <strong>
                 <span id="textKey" data-bind="text: displayKey" />    
            </strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="textValue" type="text" data-bind="value: displayValue" />
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, unfortunately in my case the keys sometimes are not fixed as I have checked again, they are not the same as sometimes I have the data like this : "{\"reference\":\"8542\",\"rion_id\":\"9861\"}" so in the table, I couldn't fix the displayKey I think